# Timing elements of a .NET C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timing

I have been looking but have not managed to find anything, is there a way to time the elements of a C# HttpWebRequest

- DNS Lookup
- SSL Negoation
- Content Request
- Server Processing
- Content Response

It possible to do it in go and a few other languages but I could not find any information on how to do this in C#

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing but you can't enable that from code, AFAICT, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213200/578411

Comment: You could use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler which has the time for each request and response,

Comment: I was hoping for a .net code option but the effort involved, I think I might look at using a different language for it as the roll your own solution will take a lot of code.